# Pass different data : ViewPager cards inspired by Duolingo

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager

I just started app developing recently and stumbled upon a problem that I basically can't figure out : https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards

He instructed that on CardPagerAdapter.java in instantiateItem, I need to set the data according to the position. But how do I do it?

I want the first card to have a title of "FIRST CARD" while the second "SECOND CARD" and so on.. hope someone could help.

**CardPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {

    private List<CardView> mViews;
    private List<CardItem> mData;
    private float mBaseElevation;

    public CardPagerAdapter() {
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCardItem(CardItem item) {
        mViews.add(null);
        mData.add(item);
    }

    public float getBaseElevation() {
        return mBaseElevation;
    }

    @Override
    public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
        return mViews.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_adapter, container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        bind(mData.get(position), view);
        CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
            mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
        }

        cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
        mViews.set(position, cardView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        mViews.set(position, null);
    }

    private void bind(CardItem item, View view) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        description.setText(item.getText());
        button.setText(item.getButton());
    }

}
```

Comment: There is already a method bind() to do that. You just need to add CardItems in this adapter using addCardItem method.

Comment: and that's what im asking.. how do i "add" them.. i need a sample code so I could understand it.

Comment: You must have the adapter's instance in your activity. Before setting the adapter to Viewpager you need to do <your_adapter_instance>. addCardItem(new CardItem(<params>))